# How to write handlers and other functions in functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component (which previously was class-based but I decided to refactor it with react hooks). So now every function which is declared inside will be declared on every rerender (In this example `handleClick`). When it was a class-based component such problem did not exist because the function was stored in the class property.
So, my question is where do such functions belong to?

Before:

```js
class Select extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       state ={
          value: props.value
       }
    }
    render() {
       return <OtherComponent click={this.handleClick} />
    }

    handleClick = (value) => {
       this.setState({value})
    }
}
```

After:

```
const Select = (props) => {
   const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);
   return <OtherComponent click={handleClick} />
   function handleClick(value) {
     setValue(value)
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those functions belong inside your main component function declaration's body.

It's weird knowing that they'll be recreated on every render, but that is the way it's meant to be done.

`useCallback` is a way that you could optmize the function re-creation, but unless you're building extremely expensive components, you'll probably never have any performance issues on this subject.

From **React Docs**, we get that:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render

> **Are Hooks slow because of creating functions in render?**
>
> No. In modern browsers, the raw performance of closures compared to classes doesn’t differ significantly except in extreme scenarios.
>
> **In addition, consider that the design of Hooks is more efficient in a couple ways:**
>
> - Hooks avoid a lot of the overhead that classes require, like the cost of creating class instances and binding event handlers in the constructor.
> - Idiomatic code using Hooks doesn’t need the deep component tree nesting that is prevalent in codebases that use higher-order components, render props, and context. With smaller component trees, React has less work to do.
>
> Traditionally, performance concerns around inline functions in React have been related to how passing new callbacks on each render breaks shouldComponentUpdate optimizations in child components. Hooks approach this problem from three sides.
>
> The useCallback Hook lets you keep the same callback reference between re-renders so that shouldComponentUpdate continues to work:

```
// Will not change unless `a` or `b` changes
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(() => {
  doSomething(a, b);
}, [a, b]);
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I thought there would be some workaround because I faced lots of articles regarding this performance problem that stated that this every time creating can cause performance problems. For example https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f
https://codeburst.io/how-to-not-react-common-anti-patterns-and-gotchas-in-react-40141fe0dcd

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useCallback` hook to memoize the function so it is only recreated when its dependencies change.

Something like this:

```
const Select = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);
  const memoizedHandleClick = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      setValue(value)
    },
  );

  return <OtherComponent click={memoizedHandleClick} />
}
```

I'd highly recommend reading the the full hooks reference, paying special attention to the function form of the useState updater (ie: `setValue(x => x + 1)`) and the second argument to useCallback which lists the dependencies of your memoized function.

Reference:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: But as I understand on every prop change in `Select` component `useCallback` function will be called and new function will be created (arrow function). And that's what concerns me. `useCallback` as I understand is used for optimizing child rerender.

Comment: Oh I see, you're worried that the function is created at all, even if it is immediately discarded and garbage collected? In that case I think you're over optimising. It's preventing the child render that's the important part.

Comment: Yeah, I'am worried mostly about garbage collection. I'm not quite sure about how it will affect application as it grows. I thought with react hooks everything can be written in fuctional components but as for me creating new function every time is a big minus and I was wondering is there any workaround

Comment: @KostyaTresko: Were you able to find out the alternate solution ? Even I am having the same concern :(